# Java API design: narrow return type in methods

Tags: java, inheritance, types, casting, api-design

Suppose I have a type family, I have defined a set of methods in base type:

```
interface Foo<T> {
   Foo<T> a();
   Foo<T> b();
   ...
}
```

And `Bar` extends `Foo`

```
interface Bar<T> extends Foo<T> {
   Bar<T> a();
   Bar<T> b();
   ...
}
```

And then `Zee` extends `Bar`

```
interface Zee<T> extends Bar<T> {
   Zee<T> a();
   Zee<T> b();
   ...
}
```

When I implement this type family with different decorators, I found I constantly write something like

```
class XBar<T> extends XFoo<T> implements Bar<T> {
   Bar<T> a() {
      return (Bar<T>)super.a();
   }
   Bar<T> b() {
      return (Bar<T>)super.b();
   }
   ...
}
```

It is really tedious. I am wondering is this normal case in Java API design or I did something wrong, or there is sort of smart way to workaround the constant typecast with one line of code?

**Updates**, To answer your comments and response, yes, method chain is one thing I want to achieve here. BTW looks like the `BaseStream` type declaration in Java8 is a good example of addressing this problem. I am trying to use that approach. Will update my progress here.

**Updates 2**, The `BaseStream` approach doesn't work when I have multiple inheritance levels. See [Java inherited Fluent method return type in multiple level hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417082/java-inherited-fluent-method-return-type-in-multiple-level-hierarchies)

Comment: You haven't described `XFoo<T>`, which doesn't help. It would be good if you could demonstrate the problem in a *complete* way - you only need a single method, and I suspect you don't need `Zee` either.

Comment: I would suggest you to remove the methods from `Bar<T>` and `Zee<T>` alltogether, and let them use those in `Foo<T>`. You can of course return a `Bar<T>` from a method with return type `Foo<T>`. If there is some issue with this, then probably you need to explain a bit more what those interfaces, and classes are supposed to do.

Comment: See my comments below to Answer #1

Answer (score 2):

Why do your subclasses need to return the subclass type?

The [Liskov Substitution Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that objects can be replaced by subtypes without altering any properties so if you code your classes correctly, then you don't need the cast especially if you are just returning the result from `super`.

The only time I can think of that has this problem is method chaining (like `builder` pattern) when you need to access extra subclass methods during the chaining... But that should be rare.

Comment: By that logic covariant return types are useless?

Comment: @MiserableVariable covariant return types must still fulfill the super class's contract so they can still be passed around as their super class type without problems.  For example, `Float` is still a `Number` so if you don't need the extra methods on `Float`, you can return it as a `Number`.

Comment: Not sure I understand. My comment was in response to your question why does subclass need to return subclass type. If there isn't a good reason for that than covariant return types are not required.

Comment: I was only questioning why this *particular* object the OP showed needed to return subtypes not the general case.  Also in general, the return type can be a subclass without modifying the interface so the caller doesn't know if the returned type is a subclass or not.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. It seemed to me you were saying they are not needed at all, ever.

Comment: okay, here is the thing. If caller holds a `Foo` type handle, then calling `handle.a()`, it is okay to return another `Foo` type reference. However, if the caller holds a `Zee` typed handle, then calling `handle.a()`, I want it return a `Zee`, instead of a `Foo`. Method chain is one scenario of this case.