# Java inherited Fluent method return type in multiple level hierarchies

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, fluent, fluent-interface

So following the solution described in [Java - Inherited Fluent method return type to return incident class' type, not parent's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13118648/java-inherited-fluent-method-return-type-to-return-incident-class-type-not-p). I want to extend it to multiple levels.

The solution works in one level obviously. Here is compiled and runnable code (no dependencies):

```
public enum X {
    ;
    static interface BaseFoo<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> {
        S foo();
    }

    static interface Foo<T> extends BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>> {
        void foo1();
    }

    static abstract class AbstractFooBase<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> implements BaseFoo<T, S> {
        abstract void internalFoo();
        @Override
        public S foo() {
            internalFoo();
            return (S)this;
        }
    }

    static class FooImpl<T> extends AbstractFooBase<T, Foo<T>> implements Foo<T> {
        @Override
        void internalFoo() {
            System.out.println("inside FooImpl::internalFoo()");
        }

        @Override
        public void foo1() {
            System.out.println("inside FooImpl::foo1()");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> foo = new FooImpl<String>();
        foo.foo().foo1();
    }
}
```

However things getting difficult when I add an new level in the object inheritance hierarchy. The code below won't compile:

```
public enum X {
    ;
    static interface BaseFoo<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> {
        S foo();
    }

    static interface Foo<T> extends BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>> {
        void foo1();
    }

    static interface BaseBar<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends BaseFoo<T, S> {
        S bar();
    }

    static interface Bar<T> extends BaseBar<T, Bar<T>> {
        void bar1();
    }

    static abstract class AbstractFooBase<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> implements BaseFoo<T, S> {
        abstract void internalFoo();
        @Override
        public S foo() {
            internalFoo();
            return (S)this;
        }
    }

    static class FooImpl<T> extends AbstractFooBase<T, Foo<T>> implements Foo<T> {
        @Override
        void internalFoo() {
            System.out.println("inside FooImpl::internalFoo()");
        }

        @Override
        public void foo1() {
            System.out.println("inside FooImpl::foo1()");
        }
    }

    static abstract class AbstractBarBase<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends FooImpl<T> implements BaseBar<T, S> {
        abstract void internalBar();
        @Override
        public S bar() {
            internalBar();
            return (S)this;
        }
    }

    static class BarImpl<T> extends AbstractBarBase<T, Bar<T>> implements Bar<T> {
        @Override
        void internalBar() {
            System.out.println("inside BarImpl::internalBar()");
        }

        @Override
        public void bar1() {
            System.out.println("inside BarImpl::bar1()");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo<String> foo = new FooImpl<String>();
        foo.foo().foo1();

        Bar<Boolean> bar = new BarImpl<Boolean>();
        bar.foo().bar1();
    }
}
```

The compile time error message is:

```
X.java:40: X.BaseFoo cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T,S> and <T,X.Foo<T>>
    static abstract class AbstractBarBase<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends FooImpl<T> implements BaseBar<T, S> {
                    ^
X.java:49: X.BaseFoo cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T,X.Bar<T>> and <T,X.Foo<T>>
    static class BarImpl<T> extends AbstractBarBase<T, Bar<T>> implements Bar<T> {
           ^
Note: X.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
2 errors
```

Any idea how to work around it?

Comment: Looks like no one loves long code in the questions. I posted another question which simplified this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19436415/basefoo-cannot-be-inherited-with-different-arguments-t-x-bart-and-t-x-foo

Answer (score 2):

This is your inheritance hierarchy:

[image: inheritance hierarchy]

As you can see, some of these types are inheriting the same interface type more than once. In fact, `BarImpl` implements `BaseFoo` four times over, and some of the inheritance chains provide differing arguments for its type parameter `S`. It can be said that `BarImpl` implements the following:

- `BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>>` (via `Foo`)
- `BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>>` (via `FooImpl`)
- `BaseFoo<T, Bar<T>>` (via `Bar`)
- `BaseFoo<T, Bar<T>>` (via `BarImpl`)

[The same interface cannot be implemented with different type arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420636/cant-include-the-same-interface-with-different-parameters), so you get a compiler error.

As I pointed out on your followup question, my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) discusses how to properly emulate the "self-type" to implement a hierarchical fluent builder pattern like you're trying to do. In it, I point out the need to maintain a variable "self-type" (`S` in your code) in all intermediate types - only resolving it with a "leaf class" that is understood to be `final`. Your code is violating that rule because the intermediate types `Foo`, `Bar`, and  `FooImpl` are prematurely resolving `S`.

The following solution resolves the issue:

```
static interface BaseFoo<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> {
    S foo();
}

static interface Foo<T, S extends Foo<T, S>> extends BaseFoo<T, S> {
    void foo1();
}

static interface BaseBar<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends BaseFoo<T, S> {
    S bar();
}

static interface Bar<T, S extends Bar<T, S>> extends BaseBar<T, S> {
    void bar1();
}

static abstract class AbstractFooBase<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> implements BaseFoo<T, S> {
    abstract void internalFoo();
    @Override
    public S foo() {
        internalFoo();
        return (S)this;
    }
}

static abstract class AbstractIntermediateFoo<T, S extends AbstractIntermediateFoo<T, S>> extends AbstractFooBase<T, S> implements Foo<T, S> {
    @Override
    void internalFoo() {
        System.out.println("inside FooImpl::internalFoo()");
    }

    @Override
    public void foo1() {
        System.out.println("inside FooImpl::foo1()");
    }
}

static final class FooImpl<T> extends AbstractIntermediateFoo<T, FooImpl<T>> { }

static abstract class AbstractBarBase<T, S extends AbstractBarBase<T, S>> extends AbstractIntermediateFoo<T, S> implements BaseBar<T, S> {
    abstract void internalBar();
    @Override
    public S bar() {
        internalBar();
        return (S)this;
    }
}

static final class BarImpl<T> extends AbstractBarBase<T, BarImpl<T>> implements Bar<T, BarImpl<T>> {
    @Override
    void internalBar() {
        System.out.println("inside BarImpl::internalBar()");
    }

    @Override
    public void bar1() {
        System.out.println("inside BarImpl::bar1()");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    FooImpl<String> foo = new FooImpl<String>();
    foo.foo().foo1();

    BarImpl<Boolean> bar = new BarImpl<Boolean>();
    bar.foo().bar1();
}
```

My changes were the following:

- Maintain `S` in `Foo`
- Maintain `S` in `Bar`
- Split `FooImpl` into the following:

  - `AbstractIntermediateFoo`, which is `abstract`, maintains `S`, and implements `internalFoo` and `foo1`.
  - `FooImpl`, which is concrete, `final`, and resolves `S`.
- Make `BarImpl` `final`.
- In `main`, declare `foo` and `bar` as `FooImpl` and `BarImpl` - coding to interface isn't feasible here.

Comment: The reason I split `BaseFoo` from `Foo` is that I don't want the user application use two generic type when they want to use `Foo`, say, I just need this code `Foo<String> foo = new MyFoo<String>()`, instead of `Foo<String, MyFoo> foo = new MyFoo<String>()`; thus I want to make `Foo` a leaf inteface, which should not have two generic type in the declaration

Comment: Coding to interface just isn't going to work with a hierarchical fluent builder. Think about what "leaf interface" implies - it's an inherent contradiction.

Comment: The `BaseStream` and `Stream` in Java 8 API is a good example of the SELF interface and LEAF interface. The only thing is it doesn't scale to multiple level, I think this is mostly because Java doesn't support mixin

Comment: I stand corrected - you're right that a leaf interface is possible. I had been thinking of a leaf type as the terminus of implementation, but you've shown me that's not necessary. I think the crux of your issue is that you want to code to interface with `Foo`, but also have `Foo` implemented by other types that "change their mind" about what `S` is. The only solution is to split `Foo` somehow, like I did with `FooImpl`. Does that help at all?

Comment: No, consider I am doing something like Java API's `Collection`, `List`, implementing the leaf as a concrete (and even final) class is not acceptable. I guess I will have to go back to the original approach that is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19256811/java-api-design-narrow-return-type-in-methods. I give you a **UP VOTE** anyway to thank you for your effort spending here ;-)