# BaseFoo cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T,X.Bar<T>> and <T,X.Foo<T>>

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, fluent, fluent-interface

This is a simplified version of [Java inherited Fluent method return type in multiple level hierarchies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19417082/java-inherited-fluent-method-return-type-in-multiple-level-hierarchies).

Given the following code:

```
public enum X {
    ;
    static interface BaseFoo<T, S extends BaseFoo<T, S>> {
        S foo();
    }

    static interface Foo<T> extends BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>> {
        void foo1();
    }

    static interface BaseBar<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends BaseFoo<T, S> {
        S bar();
    }

    static interface Bar<T> extends BaseBar<T, Bar<T>>, Foo<T> {
        void bar1();
    }

}
```

run `javac X.java` I get the error message:

```
X.java:15: error: BaseFoo cannot be inherited with different arguments: <T,X.Bar<T>> and <T,X.Foo<T>>
    static interface Bar<T> extends BaseBar<T, Bar<T>>, Foo<T> {
           ^
```

Anyone has any solution?

**Disclaim**: I am trying to use the pattern to implement the [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) across a container class inheritance hierarchy.

**Background**: to make it easier for people to understand why I need this, here is the story. I want to create a container family: `Traversal` <- `Sequence` <- `List`. So `Traversal` has a method `Traveral<T> accept(Visitor<T>)` (no [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) for short), this method should always return `this` after iterating the visitor through the elements. When I have a `List` type, I want the method return `List<T>` instead of `Traversal<T>` because I want to make it possible to call something like `myList.accept(v).head(15)`, where `head(int)` is a method of `List` not `Traversal`

Comment: My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7354740/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-type-with-a-type-variable/7355094#7355094) seems related.

Comment: @PaulBellora That is really a comprehensive answer. Nice. I guess that is what OP needs here.

Comment: Yes @PaulBellora, I read that before. But my case is about a container inheritance family, which introduce another `<T>` type. Can you come up with a solution based on my code?

Comment: Sure, I'll have a look later today if no one else takes up the challenge.

Comment: I've deleted my answer here and posted [a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19471914/697449) to the original question.

Answer (score 12):

A class or interface cannot implement or extend from different instantiation of a generic interface. Your `Bar` interface is breaking this rule. Let's examine the interface declaration:

```
static interface Bar<T> extends BaseBar<T, Bar<T>>, Foo<T>
```

So, `Bar<T>` extends two interfaces:

- `BaseBar<T, Bar<T>>`
- `Foo<T>`

In addition to that, those two interfaces extend from different instantiation of the same interface `BaseFoo`.

- `BaseBar<T, S extends BaseBar<T, S>> extends BaseFoo<T, S>`
- `Foo<T> extends BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>>`

Those inherited interfaces are eventually also the super interfaces of `Bar` interface. Thus your `Bar` interface tries to extend from 2 different instantiation of `BaseFoo`, which is illegal. Let's understand the reason using a simple example:

```
// Suppose this was allowed
class Demo implements Comparable<Demo> , Comparable<String> {
    public int compareTo(Demo arg)     { ... } 
    public int compareTo(String arg) { ... } 
}
```

then after type erasure, compiler would generate 2 bridge methods, for both the generic method. The class is translated to:

```
class Demo implements Comparable<Demo> , Comparable<String> {
    public int compareTo(Demo arg)     { ... } 
    public int compareTo(String arg) { ... } 

    // Bridge method added by compiler
    public int compareTo(Object arg)     { ... } 
    public int compareTo(Object arg) { ... } 
}
```

So, that results in creation of duplicates bridge method in the class. That is why it is not allowed.

Comment: I know it is illegal, while what I need is how to resolve or work around it. Come to the case, `Bar<T>` is a type of `Foo<T>` so I suppose the root `BaseFoo<T, Foo<T>>` could be replaced as `BaseFoo<T, Bar<T>`, which is the same as another inheritance route via `BaseBar`, isn't it?

Comment: @green No it's not like that. A `List<Number>` is not a `List<Integer>`. The convariant relationship between types don't follow while using generics.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. Anyway to work achieve what I want, ie. a fluent API across a container hierarchy?

Comment: @green I would have to look into what a Fluent API is. Or you can explain in brief what you are trying to do. May be with some more code.

Comment: So basically I want create a container family of `Traversal` <- `Sequence` <- `List`, while there are some method defined to return `this` to facilitate fluent method call, like `myTrv.map(myMapFunc).filter(myFilterFunc)`, and when your instance is of `List` type, then your `map()` and `filter()` should return a `List`, instead of `Traversal`, so that you can write code like `myLst.map(mapFunc).head(5).append(anotherLst)`, where `head(n)` and `append(...)` are `List` method but not `Traversal` method. Java8's `BaseStream` and `Stream` class use this pattern, but only in one level.